Installing JupyterLab on Debian 12
Good afternoon!
I want to use JupyterLab, but cannot succeed in installation of it for long time...
My system:
> lsb_release -d && uname -r
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
6.3.0-2-amd64

> python3 --version
Python 3.11.2

> jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 6.17.0
ipywidgets       : 6.0.0
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 4.12.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.3
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.7.2
nbconvert        : 6.5.3
nbformat         : 5.5.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.5.0

> ls /usr/bin/ | grep 'jupyter'
jupyter
jupyter-bundlerextension
jupyter-console
jupyter-dejavu
jupyter-execute
jupyter-kernel
jupyter-kernelspec
jupyter-migrate
jupyter-nbconvert
jupyter-nbextension
jupyter-notebook
jupyter-run
jupyter-server
jupyter-serverextension
jupyter-troubleshoot
jupyter-trust

There is no jupyterlab in the apt output:
# apt search jupyter | grep 'jupyter' | grep -v '^  '

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

jupyter/stable,stable,now 4.12.0-1 all [installed]
jupyter-client/stable,stable,now 7.4.9-2 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-console/stable,stable,now 6.4.4-2 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-core/stable,stable,now 4.12.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-nbconvert/stable,stable,now 6.5.3-3 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-nbextension-jupyter-js-widgets/stable,stable,now 6.0.0-11 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-nbformat/stable,stable,now 5.5.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-notebook/stable,stable,now 6.4.12-2.2 all [installed,automatic]
jupyter-qtconsole/stable,stable 5.4.0-1 all
jupyter-server/stable,stable,now 1.23.3-1 all [installed]
jupyter-sphinx-theme-common/stable,stable 0.0.6+ds1-11 all
jupyter-sphinx-theme-doc/stable,stable 0.0.6+ds1-11 all
jupyterhub/stable,stable 3.0.0+ds1-1 all
jupyterlab-desktop/now 4.2.5-1 amd64 [installed,local]
macaulay2-jupyter-kernel/stable,stable 0.6.7~beta-3 all
python-jupyter-client-doc/stable,stable 7.4.9-2 all
python-jupyter-console-doc/stable,stable 6.4.4-2 all
python-jupyter-core-doc/stable,stable 4.12.0-1 all
python3-jupyter-client/stable,stable,now 7.4.9-2 all [installed,automatic]
python3-jupyter-console/stable,stable,now 6.4.4-2 all [installed,automatic]
python3-jupyter-core/stable,stable,now 4.12.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-jupyter-kernel-test/stable,stable 0.4.5-1 all
python3-jupyter-packaging/stable,stable 0.12.3-1.1 all
python3-jupyter-server/stable,stable,now 1.23.3-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-jupyter-server-mathjax/stable,stable 0.2.3-2 all
python3-jupyter-sphinx-theme/stable,stable 0.0.6+ds1-11 all
python3-jupyter-telemetry/stable,stable 0.1.0-4 all
python3-jupyterlab-pygments/stable,stable,now 0.2.2-3 all [installed,automatic]
python3-jupyterlab-server/stable,stable,now 2.16.5-1 all [installed]
sagemath-jupyter/stable,stable 9.5-6 all

I tried to use pip3, but obtained error:
> pip3 install jupyterlab
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

The same in the super-user mode.
I did pipx install jupyterlab, it succeeded, but jupyter-lab is not seen all the same.
I have installed a desktop application from GitHub (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop). It runs, but from the list {New notebook..., New session..., Open file..., Open folder..., Connect...} only active action is the last one. When I press that line, in the emerging window there is a field "Local JupyterLab Servers" with "No locally running JupyterLab server found" message.
Probably this is the problem with at least desktop application from GitHub. I don't know how to solve it.
I know, there is a way to install JupyterLab with Conda. I would like to avoid this.
I saw this topic,
Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found,
but didn't find a solution. Some of aforementioned actions are taken from there.
Could somebody help me to get JupyterLab working, please?

Update
I have succeeded to get the GitHub JupyterLab application working through installation some environment suggested in the start window.
Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce all details... In general, the procedure contracted to pressing some link in the start window. It installed everything it needed, and then the application started to work.

Would you like to install mini/anaconda?  https://www.anaconda.com/download

I didn't look over the entire list that you show when you run jupyter --version, but your versions of ipywidgets and notebook are old. In particular ipywidgets. I'm not sure how you are installing things? But this is not the way. pip is telling you whatever you are doing or did is not the way either. It doesn't say things like that when all is well. Someone posted very detailed notes on how to install miniconda (with conda-forge as the only channel to avoid licensing issues) yesterday or in the last few days. I don't have access right now to look up my notes but that would be a way to go.

See here with some options about minconda with conda-forge setting and miniforge. The latter option is brought up in this comment by FlyingTeller.

Thank you for the responses!
@Wayne
Yes, the installation of Jupyter looks not perfect... I have installed it some time ago, I don't remember how, but it was definitely one of apt install or pip3 install. Probably something is wrong with my repositories etc.
As I wrote, I wouldn't like to deal with Conda/Anaconda/MiniConda/... I would prefer installation with standard system tools. The GitHub variant looks good for me, so I will stop on it.

You'll need to clean your system out of all the old stuff if you aren't going to use management software that will isolate things. Because of the complexities involved, standard system tools not used in conjunction with environment management are not advised.
